# How to get first column name from table in sqlite +phonegap

Tags: mysql, sqlite, cordova

can you please tell me how to get the first column name from table in sqlite +phonegap.
I have  a table name "student".having column name ID , name , Rollnumber .

How to get column name using query?

I try like this
var str=tx.executeSql('SELECT 0 FROM student');
    alert("str"+str);
But getting error

First I create  a table

```
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CaseTable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, CaseName TEXT NOT NULL,CaseDate INTEGER ,TextArea TEXT NOT NULL)');

Before Insert i need to check



             checkExitingFolderName();
    function checkExitingFolderName(){
    db.transaction(getallTableCntend, errorCB);
    }

function getallTableCntend(tx) {
    var str=tx.executeSql('SELECT 1 FROM CaseTable WHERE ID=1');
    alert("str"+str);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you need the column **name**?

Comment: actually i need to get check duplicate item..I need to check whether the element present or not in that column .or not  before insert

Comment: Please add example data and expected output.

Comment: Why not add a `UNIQUE` constraint to the schema, and let the RDBMS handle this for you?

Comment: I also try like that But not work

Comment: tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CaseTable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, CaseName TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,CaseDate INTEGER ,TextArea TEXT NOT NULL)');

Comment: It's not work with i also try like That Insert or IGNORE

Comment: can you please give me some simple example without inserting dublicate item..

Comment: You can't define a `UNIQUE` constraint on the full width of a `TEXT` type column.  What is the longest possible value you wish to support for `CaseName`?

Comment: do some favour please change my code .or provide example

Comment: tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CaseTable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, CaseName unique varchar(255) NOT NULL ,CaseDate INTEGER ,TextArea TEXT NOT NULL)');

Comment: I also try like this not working

Answer (score 0):

Please use the link to the Intel XDK third party plugin. Before that please download the project dependency jar file from github and create the directory with cordova plugin SQLite name and place the file in it, include the jar file. Then try to add the plugin using URL .

See the whole code below 1.create datbase 2.add table 3.add data to table 4.get data from table

> 

```
 // Wait for Cordova to load
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is ready
function onDeviceReady() {
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    alert("Start ");
    var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: 'my.db', location: 'default' }, function () {


     alert("database creatred");
     db.transaction(function (tx) {
         tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE customerAccounts (firstname, lastname, acctNo)');
         alert("Table create");

         addItem("first", "last", 100);
         getData("last");

     }, function (error) {
         alert('transaction error: ' + error.message);
     }, function () {
        alert('transaction ok');
     });


    }, function (error) {
    });

 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////   


function addItem(first, last, acctNum) {
  alert("start adding");
    db.transaction(function (tx) {

        var query = "INSERT INTO customerAccounts (firstname, lastname, acctNo) VALUES (?,?,?)";
          alert("start insterting");
        tx.executeSql(query, [first, last, acctNum], function(tx, res) {
            console.log("insertId: " + res.insertId + " -- probably 1");
            console.log("rowsAffected: " + res.rowsAffected + " -- should be 1");
            alert("insert complete");
        },
        function(tx, error) {
            alert('INSERT error: ' + error.message);
        });
    }, function(error) {
        alert('transaction error: ' + error.message);
    }, function() {
        alert('transaction ok');
    });
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

    function getData(last) {

    db.transaction(function (tx) {
          alert("get data");
        var query = "SELECT firstname, lastname, acctNo FROM customerAccounts WHERE lastname = ?";
           alert("get data working");
        tx.executeSql(query, [last], function (tx, resultSet) {

            for(var x = 0; x < resultSet.rows.length; x++) {
                alert("First name: " + resultSet.rows.item(x).firstname +
                    ", Acct: " + resultSet.rows.item(x).acctNo);
            }
        },
        function (tx, error) {
            alert('SELECT error: ' + error.message);
        });
    }, function (error) {
        alert('transaction error: ' + error.message);
    }, function () {
        alert('transaction ok');
    });
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    

}
```